# Incorrect cell count with viewshed analysis

Tags: arcmap, viewshed

I am performing several viewshed analyses. As I wanted to observe how the viewshed changes when setting a different value for OffsetA I noticed something strange was going on with the cell count.

Firstly, I performed the analysis without an offset value. These were the results:

[image: Viewshed analysis without Offset value]

The attribute table states that the cell count is 208141. 
Then I performed another analysis with an OffsetA of 2m, and I got these results:

[image: Viewshed analysis with offset 2m]

Obviously, the viewshed is larger (which I expected it to be), but the cell count as mentioned in the attribute table is lower (113111).

Since I set invisible cells to be returned as NoData, I suspected it might had something to do with that. Therefore I performed the analysis again, but without selecting the option for invisible cells to be displayed as NoData.

This did not change anything and the results were exactly the same.

Am I doing something wrong or am I overlooking something? 
I am using ArcMap 10.3.

Comment: Are you working within a file geodatabase, when preforming this analysis?

Comment: Yes, I am. Could that be causing the problem?

Comment: It is possible, typically I would say no. Try using it outside of the geodatabase environment, to troubleshoot.

Comment: I tried running it outside the geodatabase, but no success. I think I might have found a solution though. Initially, I used the Visibility tool with the frequency setting to calculate the viewshed, however, when I use the regular Viewshed tool the count value for the 2m viewshed has 7 digits instead of 6.

Comment: On further investigation I found that a default attribute table is only displaying 6 digits. I have changed this around by right-clicking the field properties in the attribute table and specifying with the number format option, that I wanted more digits to be displayed. This seemed to have been the problem all along! Thanks for taking the time to look for a solution!

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution to my problem. I never knew that a default ArcMap attribute table only stores numbers up to 6 digits. However, you can specify the amount of digits you want to display by formatting the numeric fields of the attribute table (see also [here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/tables/formatting-numeric-fields-in-tables.htm)). When I specified the number of significant digits to 8 and applied the changes, the attribute table updated and a larger count value was displayed for the 2m viewshed (7 digits instead of 6).